# My site does not load but downloads a file (wordpress)

Tags: pages, troubleshooting

Can someone help me to find a solution for my site. when I install a cache plugin either WP rocket or W3 Cache my site gives a download file when I try to access it and the page wont load.

this all returns to normal when I disable it.

I'm running this on Vultr High frq. on openlightspeed.

my site is inkmattic.com

This has been driving me crazy. Any help or pointing me to the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: there is a chance it could be related to .htaccess file and check this out, maybe it helps https://www.deweyjames.com/wordpress-download-file-instead-of-opening-site/ I had similar problem and this was an issue

Comment: Try deactivating other plugins and check with the Cache plugin developers to ensure their plugin is compatible and check with OpenLightSpeed to ensure that caching plugins are compatible.  Also, if you have full control of the server, drop the caching plugins and configure caching on the server itself.

Comment: @BakarL links can be used to support an answer, but they can't **be** the answer itself, answers have to be self contained and useful on their own, you can't rely on the user reading an offsite link, I've converted it to a comment, but if you can extract the solution and post it as a solution rather than a link that would be fine

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I ended up switching web servers to Nginx which sorted the issues

Answer (score 0):

I switched web servers from openlitespeed to nginx which fixed the issue

Comment: Glad you solved the problem, but openlitespeed should work fine with WordPress. I guess it's your caching plugins that aren't compatible with it, so it might be worth telling them about this if you haven't already,